# TypeScript can't detect null pointer when key missing in Object

Tags: typescript

Let's consider this code. TypeScript can't detect that there's an error.

```
let map: { [key: string]: string } = {}
map['key'].toUpperCase()
```

Is there a way to fix that?

P.S.

There's slightly different form

```
let map: { [key: string]: string | null } = {}
```

But, it's not exactly what I want. I want to specify that

```
key may not exist, but if it exists it's a string
```

and this form specifies

```
key may not exist, but even if it exists, it could be a string or null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest that a better form is: `Key is always accessible, and the value is string or undefined`. Because this is what the nature of javascript will give you.

And you can define that by `T | undefined`:

```
let map: { [key: string]: string | undefined } = {}

var hopefullyString = map['key'];
if (hopefullyString != undefined)
    return hopefullyString.toUpperCase();
```

If TypeScript would have a sounder type system, the would have been enabled by the `strictNullChecks`-flag in the compiler configuration. However, in striving for general usability, they make some unsound design choices here and there. And this is unfortunately one of those cases, more background [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9235).